# How can I return only the self._id without none in the output

Tags: python, class, iterator

```
def check_id_valid(id_number):
    int_list_id = [int(num) for num in list(str(id_number))]

    i = -1
    a_list = []

    for num in int_list_id:
        i += 1
        if i % 2 == 0:
            a_list.append(num)

        else:
            a_list.append(num * 2)

    # return a_list = [1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7, 16, 2]

    b_list = []

    for num in a_list:
        if num < 10:
            b_list.append(num)

        else:
            convert_num = list(str(num))
            b_list.append(sum([int(n) for n in convert_num]))

    # return b_list = [1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 3, 7, 7, 2]

    if sum(b_list) % 10 == 0:
        return True

    else:
        return False


print(check_id_valid(123456780))  # = False
print(check_id_valid(123456782))  # = True


class IDIterator:

    def __init__(self, id):
        self._id = id
        


    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self._id += 1

        if check_id_valid(self._id):
            if self._id < 1000000000:
                return self._id

            else:
                raise StopIteration




id_iter = iter(IDIterator(123456780))

for id in id_iter:
    print(id)
```

output:

```
None
123456782
None
None
None
```

Comment: maybe inside `__next__` you should run loop which repeate `self._id += 1` when `check_id_valid(self._id)` gives `False`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for id in id_iter:
    if id:
        print(id)
```